# What are the available packages for sentimental analysis in r?

Tags: r, svm, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes, sentimentr

There are various packages available to perform sentiment analysis in R: sentimentalanalysis,syuzhet, sentimentr and many more. actually i just want sentimensts - positive, neutral, and negative. so as to predict stock movement or justify it's movement

Comment: I really like `tidytext`. For an example of Warren Buffett annual letters, see this recent blog post from one of the authors: https://juliasilge.com/blog/tidytext-0-1-3/

Comment: also https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSentiment/index.html

Comment: there is only one way to do this. take some text and run benchmark sentiment analysis using different packages and manually see and check the results. all the best!

Comment: Compare accuracy... I have done some here. 
 https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr#comparing-sentimentr-syuzhet-meanr-and-stanford. tidytext implements the same dictionaries already available in syuzhet but require more code as tidytext is a framework not specific to sentiment as Jockers has done.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should go for `tidytext` : https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext. You'll get access to four sentiment dictionaries :

- `affin`
- `bing`
- `nrc`
- `loughran`

You can get a list of all the available sentiments here with `get_sentiments("AFINN")` / `get_sentiments("loughran")`...

Here's a description of how to perform sentiment the analysis in R : http://tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html

This package is not only for sentiment analysis but for text mining, the tidy way. Worth taking some time to learn and use it.